# Decode PDU encoded SMS in PHP

Tags: php, sms, pdu

I've searched the web for quite a while now - but nothing usable passed my way :(

Do you know a class/library to decode PDU encoded SMS using PHP?
Doing all the decode by hand using the official documentation scares me a bit.
There seem to be libraries for use in Java (Android) but that does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [javaScript based GUI](http://www.rednaxela.net/pdu.php). paste your pdu message in middle box in click convert button.

Comment: Sorry, I'm searching for a class/library to do the encoding - a GUI for manual encoding does not help.

Comment: library is already there but in javascript. you can save that page, extract javascrtip library and then translate it into PHP.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in PHP based on [python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19531128/1065703):

```
<?php
/**
 * Decode 7-bit packed PDU messages
 */
if ( !function_exists( 'hex2bin' ) ) {
    // pre 5.4 fallback
    function hex2bin( $str ) {
        $sbin = "";
        $len = strlen( $str );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 2 ) {
            $sbin .= pack( "H*", substr( $str, $i, 2 ) );
        }

        return $sbin;
    }
}

function pdu2str($pdu) {
    // chop and store bytes
    $number = 0;
    $bitcount = 0;
    $output = '';
    while (strlen($pdu)>1) {
        $byte = ord(hex2bin(substr($pdu,0,2)));
        $pdu=substr($pdu, 2);
        $number += ($byte << $bitcount);
        $bitcount++ ;
        $output .= chr($number & 0x7F);
        $number >>= 7;
        if (7 == $bitcount) {
            // save extra char
            $output .= chr($number);
            $bitcount = $number = 0;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function DecodePDU($sString = '')
{
    $sString = pack("H*",$sString);
    $sString = mb_convert_encoding($sString,'UTF-8','UCS-2');

    return $sString;
}
```

Comment: Please also comment on the code to be more educative.

Comment: SMS PDU encoding is not UCS-2.

Comment: Did your really put "s" prefix to indicate that "sString" variable is of type "string"? :|

Comment: Yes, $sString - type "string"
$nValue - type "int"
$fValue - type "float"