# How to encode SMS PDU in php

Tags: php, ussd, gammu

I was trying to apply AT commands on my Huawei modem using gammu. I can use following commands to access USSD from ZTE Modem:

```
gammu getussd *111#
```

but in huawei modem, it doesn't work. As per my study, I need to provide PDU instead of text. Then I used [this](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=288) link to encode my code *111# and try following on command line.

```
gammu getussd AA582C3602
```

and it works!. **Now I need to convert *111# to AA582C3602 using php.**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367221/decode-pdu-encoded-sms-in-php) link describe how to decode PDU Encoded message. but I didn't find any reverse way to convert back the normal text into PDU encoded message.

Badly need your help.

Comment: What Huawei modem is that? This should be really fixed in Gammu, have you filed report as described in http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/?

Answer (score 1):

Some Huawei modems don't support USSD... E220 doesn't... I'm using E1550 in Portugal for NOS (old Optimus) operator with no issues, but yes it's PDU encoded.

Tell the modem you will be sending PDU encoded whith AT+CMGF=0.

I use this commands prior to send the USSD

AT+CMGF=0

AT+CSCS="IRA"